# Bootstrap 3 Modal isn't working with the theme

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using this theme http://www.bootply.com/render/85779# to create a mobile website. I'm trying to implement a modal but it doesn't seem to be working with this theme. I have the proper code implemented in my CSS and JS file, what could be wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Storystrap Template</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"> 
              <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <!--/stories-->
                  <div class="row">    
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 text-center">
                      <a class="story-title" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://api.randomuser.me/portraits/thumb/men/58.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px" class="img-circle"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9">
                      <h3>In n Out</h3>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                          <h4><span class="label label-default">4 spots left</span></h4><h4>
                          <small style="font-family:courier,'new courier';" class="text-muted">Leaves at 1PM  • <a href="#" class="text-muted">Returns at 2PM</a></small>
                          </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                          <button type ="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btnNext" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#moreModal">More <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
                          <!-- <ul>
                            <li></li>
                          </ul> -->
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br><br>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                  <!--/stories-->   
                </div>
              </div>                                                
            </div><!--/col-12-->
          </div>
          <div class="modal" id="moreModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="moreModal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-header">
               <p>did it work</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are missing `<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` and please verify that `botstrap.min.js` and `jquery.min.js` are properly linked

Comment: Are you loading the bootstrap modal script? Is there anything in the browser's error log?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing jquery and modal.js.
You don't need the entire bootstrap.min.js library just download all from the official site and find the modal.js file and add it to your site after jquery.